# Error correction : If we had Sachin in our team, we would have won the match against your team

Tags: exam-questions

> If we had Sachin in our team, we would have won the match against your team.

Which is the correct way to correct this sentence ?
I have learned that the general form of a wish of present is something like this if I **were** you I **would** study more.

And for wishes of past the form is like If he **had** a few hours to spare, he **would have** spent them in a public library.

But I think the **had** in the question which I asked and the **had** in the example which I gave is not same. So how do I correct the sentence ?

In this way

> If we **had had** Sachin in our team, we would have won the match against your team.

Or

> If we had Sachin in our team, we **would  win** the match against your  team.

Comment: _If we had had Sachin in our team, we would have won the match against your team,_ or a bit literary/formal: _Had we had Sachin in our team, we would have won the match against your team._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it right conditional sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123632/is-it-right-conditional-sentence)

Comment: You need past perfect *(**had had**)* if what you're trying to say is that you'd have won *if Sachin had been in your team **in the past, when you played the match*** (with no particular implication as to whether he's in the team *now*, or even whether you're thinking about the *current* team line-up at all). If you use simple past *(**had**)*, you're imagining a hypothetical current situation where he ***is*** in the team (with the implication that if he were, he'd also have been there at the time of the game). So both are acceptable - it's just a matter of intended nuance.

Comment: ...note that your final example is speculating about the outcome of a ***future*** game, not one that you've already played and lost.

Answer (score -1):

The error is different. We normally say someone is *on* a team.

> If we had Sachin **on** our team, we would have won the match against your team.

I am not aware of a specific reason, but this definition of [*on*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on_1) may work:

> 23. *preposition*
>       You use on to introduce an activity that someone is doing, particularly travelling.
>       *Students **on** the full-time course of study are usually sponsored.*

(AmE disclaimer...)

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but it seems *in* is simply [more common in BrE](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=58398399). Note that these sentence correction questions are usually asked by Indians, and they're supposed to teach some sort of archaic/formal BrE.

Comment: @userr2684291 Could be, I'll add the standard disclaimer. The OP should add their locale in this case. I'll wait to see what other answers show up.